# Newly purchased range hood is supposed to be for 10" ducting, but the transition mount that came with the hood is only 9.5 inches. What should I do?

Tags: kitchens, venting, hood, range-hood

I recently purchased a range hood that is supposed to work with 10" ducts, but when I measured the transition mount that came with the hood (pictured below), it's actually only 9.5" in diameter. This is not even a size that's offered by the manufacturer (they only offer sizes like 6", 8", and 10"). I wonder what I can do about it. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Get a 10" duct and some duct tape to seal.

Comment: Some people say that a duct that is above needs to fit inside a connecting duct that is below. Following this logic, a 10" duct would need to fit inside the mount opening, which is not possible. Would that be a problem?

Comment: 10" pipe  goes over it.